# Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}H_n}{n+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know alternating series test so I can figure out this series converge.
But I don't know the result of this infinity series.
I try to solve this problem in various way, for example taylor series, abel's partial summation formula, and harmonic number but still I can't solve it. I need your help. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you write down the sum in its expanded form then it would be helpful?

Comment: Note that the multiples summands are simply $H_{n+1}$, where $H_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: You could begin by simplifying: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+1/2+…+1/n+1/(n+1))}{n+2} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(1+1/2+…+1/n)}{n+1}$